# How does closures capture data?

Tags: swift

I don't understand this concept that a closure captures data.. Can someone write a sample code using closures that show how data never gets destroyed.. I already read the Apple documents and I'm still confused. And also how does 'unowned' and 'weak' make any difference in a closure...

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var allWords = [String]()
var usedWords = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let allWordsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "start", ofType: "txt"){

        if let startWords = try? String(contentsOfFile: allWordsPath){

            allWords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")

        }else{

            allWords = ["Cake"]
        }

        startGame()
    }

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Make Word", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector (makeWord))
}

func startGame(){

    allWords = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: allWords) as! [String]
    title = allWords[0]
    usedWords.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return usedWords.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Word", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = usedWords[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}


func makeWord() {

    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add Word", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)


    let submit = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default){ [unowned self,ac]

        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        let answer = ac.textFields?[0]
        self.submit(answer: (answer?.text)!)

        }

    ac.addAction(submit)
    present(ac,animated: true)
}


var number = 10
func submit(answer: String){
    usedWords.append(answer)
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

how does unowned work here if we are not explicitly deallocating things..

Comment: http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/closures/2016/07/25/closure-capture-1/

Comment: I don't understand his example.

Comment: Check my answer. Btw closures don't ensure your data never gets destroyed. They simply allow you to specify how the data should be handled, and what to do in case it is destroyed. Its perfectly valid to have a variable set as "weak" and then simply check it inside the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first search for the difference between strong, weak, and unowned. There are PLENTY of answers here on SO about it.

Anyways, in this specific case:

Your closure has this code:

```
[unowned self,ac]
```

This is called  a "capture list". It indicates the things that should be "captured" by value WHEN THE BLOCK is created. (if you don't specify them here, and you change the value somewhere after the block, the value inside the block would also be changed).

The reason why self is unowned and doesn't require to be deallocated is because unowned means:

> "Don't worry about memory management for this variable, it will ALWAYS
>   have a value for the duration of my closure"

So, going back to unowned self, the reason you should declare weak or unowned the self variable from a closure is because if not you would create a retain cycle. Things can't be deallocated as long as something is referencing them. So in this case, your TableViewController is keeping your closure alive, and your closure is keeping your TableViewController alive. So because they are referencing each other none of them can get deallocated properly. -> Memory Leak

So we can conclude that self has to either be weak or unowned. For all intents and purposes in this example they are exactly the same. They both serve the purpose of "breaking the retain cycle" by removing the ability of the closure to keep self alive. So who will dealloc self you ask? your closure doesn't care. But think outside your closure. Your closure is being called by your TableViewController, so since there's no weird things going on here we can safely assume that, if there is an alert being shown it must definitively be shown over your TableViewController. So once you dismiss the alert or whatever, your TableViewController will keep working as usual. One you dismiss your TableViewController though, self WILL be deallocated (since the closure is referencing it as unowned), but by this point there is no way the alert is being shown. If you however do some weird things that make your TableViewController be dismissed WHILE the alert is still being shown, then once the user "submits" your app will crash. BECAUSE by declaring your variable unowned you basically made a promise to your closure that it wouldn't have to worry about the self entity, as it would always exist as long as your closure was alive.

Comment: So basically if we don't put unowned or weak, the properties inside the closure will be affected by changes outside? Or are they only needed for deallocating purposes...Also, all properties of viewController has reference to itself so how do they deallocate.

Comment: You are mixing stuff. Unowned or Weak are not related to if they are modified outside. OK so first, stuff inside the brackets [ properties ] won't be affected by stuff happening outside. Second, weak and unowned are needed for deallocating purposes. TO AVOID retain cycles., Third, all the properties from the viewController are kept alive by the viewController itself, that is "Self". They are deallocated when the viewcontroller is deallocated, which happens when you dismiss it. This has nothing to do with the closure, you just have to ensure the closure is only used while the VC is alive.

Comment: Oh okay, one last thing: What's so bad about a memory leak.. I can just ignore the unowned or weak and just leave it.

Comment: You get a memory leak by passing a strong reference to a closure and this passed thing happens to also be keeping the closure alive. If you ignore memory leaks your app will eventually run out of memory. It's not so noticeable with small & simple classes. But for example, if you were leaking "Image" objects or other resource heavy stuff then the system would have no way of recovering back this memory and eventually kill your app.

Comment: Oh okay. Is there a easy way for the compiler to detect a memory leak so we can go back and add weak/unown?

Comment: Profiler, under xcode tools theres one made specifically for Memory Leaks. (you should google for xcode profiler or something)

Comment: Last one.. If instead I make a function and plug it into the handler parameter, do I still need to be aware of retain cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I'm creating 2 objects of the same kind. One has a reference to a closure that retains itself, so even if the function that created it goes out of scope, the object and the closure retain each other and never get released. The second object's closure has a weak reference to the object, and so when the object creating function goes out of scope, the reference count is 0, and when it gets released it releases the closure as well.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class B {

    deinit {
        print("\(name) deinit")
    }

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    var zort: (() -> ())?

    func someMethod() {
        print("")
    }
}

func createStuffThatNeverGoesAway() {

    var b: B = B(name: "bad");
    b.zort = {
        b.someMethod()
    }
}

func createStuffThatGoesAway() {

    var b: B = B(name: "good");
    b.zort = { [weak b] in
        b?.someMethod()
    }
}

createStuffThatNeverGoesAway()
createStuffThatGoesAway()
```

Output:

```
good deinit
```